# Extract string resources from source code in bulk operation using Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android app where the GUI strings and other strings are directly in the source code. I would like to extract them to a resource file.

What's the best way to do this without going to each and every string and hit ALT + ENTER?

Comment: you should add it to your resource file from the very beginning. now, start doing it one by one :D

Comment: :D Thanks, great help!

Comment: Surely, by now, someone will have come up with at least a fancy script...